# unique field validation using react formik

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, formik

I have been trying to implement a validation logic for unique field using react formik. I have tried the following approach so far and not sure why the validation error seems not be displaying or the validation logic is not working...

```
    const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    const uniqueNameValidation = (values) => sleep(2000).then(() => {
       let errors={};
       if (['admin', 'null', 'god'].includes(values.name)) {
          errors.description = 'Nice try';
       }
      return errors;
   });
```

And then in my field,I am using the function like this:

```
    <div className="form-item">
      <Label htmlFor="Name">Name</Label>
      <Field name="name" className="form-item--name" validate={uniqueNameValidation} />
      {errors.name && touched.name && <div>{errors.name}</div>}
    </div>
```

Any Helps?
Here is the demo link as well... 
https://codesandbox.io/s/young-violet-12216?file=/src/AddForm.js